# Is it possible to modify error/exit code?

Tags: install4j

We want to use the exit code from our update application to check whether

1. the update was successful
2. exited with an error
3. an update was not available.

The exit code for point 2 is greater zero, so this is easy to check. But there is no difference between point 1 and 3. Both of them exited with code 0. If I want to start the update application by a shell script or directly from our application, I can't differ whether there was a successfully update or not. So can I modify the exit code in the install4j configuration and maybe give an exit code "99" to point 3?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

That is currently not possible, but you could guard the invocation of the updater with an update check:

```
if (UpdateChecker.getUpdateDescriptor(UPDATES_XML_URL, ApplicationDisplayMode.GUI)
     .getPossibleUpdateEntry() != null) 
{
    // start updater
}
```

---

**2017-01-19 Correction:**

It is possible to set the exit code by calling

```
context.finish(exitCode)
```